# IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 11, while list has 12 elements

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, bounds, out

I have read multiple posts on index error but they all were starting from 1; Here I have started from index 0, yet I have an error

I am reading a file with 12 columns with this:

```
    fid.shape
    for j in range(ny):
        for i in range(nx): 
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,0] = fid["a1"][count]
            print "col0"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,1] = fid["a2"][count]
            print "col1"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,2] = fid["a3"][count]
            print "col2"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,3] = fid["a4"][count]
            print "col3"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,4] = fid["a5"][count]
            print "col4"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,5] = fid["a6"][count]
            print "col5"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,6] = fid["a7"][count]
            print "col6"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,7] = fid["a8"][count]
            print "col7"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,8] = fid["a9"][count]
            print "col8"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,9] = fid["a10"][count]
            print "col9"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,10] = fid["a11"][count]
            print "col10"
            fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,11] = fid["a12"][count]
            print "col11"
            count += 1
```

Since the number of columns is 12 => highest index would be 11. But I am getting this :

```
    (61104, 12)
     col0
     col1
     col2
     col3
     col4
     col5
     col6
     col7
     col8
     col9
     col10
     Traceback (most recent call last):
         fieldMatrix[fcount,i,j,11] = fid["a12"][count]
     IndexError: index 11 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 11
```

Comment: There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.

Comment: All jokes aside if the size is 11 then the highest index is 10 since you start from 0.

Comment: What is the shape of `fieldMatrix`?

Comment: @marxmacher  the size is 12.

Comment: @JLewkovich shape of fieldMatrix(100,402,152,11)

Comment: yep... that's there.  I had to increase size of fieldMatrix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the shape of fieldMatrix:

```
    (100,402,152,11)
```

I had to increase the size of fieldMatrix for the 12th element.

```
    (100,402,152,12)
```